# Does NSClassFromString check work going forward in iOS Version

Tags: ios, ios6

I don't yet have time to fully going into iOS mods and building but I need to get another update out with iOS 5.1 and 4.4 SDK. I want to change one displayed button for people on iOS now. Not sure if this would work or not. I'm basically going forward instead of backward with a NSClassFromString check. Is this build specific or is it just based on the built SDK version? I just want to check to see the iOS version to know what to show and where on the screen. Pure old school functionality with nothing new for iOS6 but I am building with 5.1 and targeting to 3.0 (still).

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UICollectionView")) {

        //  Here is old code to show a simple button
        //  that only shows differently for iOS6

} else {  // same old button that will work as before on older devices

}
```

Thanks for any thoughts you may have...

Comment: It will work fine assuming UICollectionView is the class you are attempting to use or not use.

Comment: No, UICollectionView really has nothing to do with it. Does that really matter for a IF statement? I just want to ask about iOS6. That was the most common thing I found in discussions.

Comment: Then you are doing something funny. I don't understand exactly what...

Comment: Yeah it is odd. I just want to show a certain button change only to iOS6 users who now have the new Maps. It just sends them into the app with a point, doesn't use MapKit in it. The older iOS doesn't need the button since the new Maps aren't there. This seemed like the best type of way from Apple.

Comment: Why don't you test for the availability of that feature?

Comment: Testing seems to work from what I see but was hoping that someone else out there at some point tested forward against something that wasn't there yet in that build. But everyone seems to go backward with if tests.

I can't build with the old iOS and load on the new iOS the normal way with my own devices, while device is connected or in simulator, so I have to create it like for a beta tester. So I don't trust it a 100%. I have a small app submitted with it so I will see what happens when live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make code only available in version a.b.c and after, wrap it in a run-time version check:

```
if ([@"a.b.c" compare:UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending) {
    // only available in a.b.c. and after
}
```

However, in general it is better *not* to make any assumptions about the OS version (or the device type), and instead check explicitly for the functionality to be present. Indeed use `NSClassFromString(..)` to see if a class is available. Use `[object respondsToSelector:]` to see if an object supports a certain method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ask for the ios version directly?

```
NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([version hasPrefix:@"6"]) {
    //  Here is old code to show a simple button
    //  that only shows differently for iOS6
} else {  // same old button that will work as before on older devices

}
```

EDIT:

Future iOS version safe code (yea, not as pretty) :

```
NSInteger major = 0;
NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSRange seperator = [version rangeOfString:@"."];
if (seperator.location != NSNotFound)
    major = [[version subStringToIndex:range.location] integerValue];
else
    major = [version integerValue];

if (major >= 6) {
    //  Here is old code to show a simple button
    //  that only shows differently for iOS6
} else {  // same old button that will work as before on older devices

}
```

Comment: This isn't how Apple recommend to do this. The runtime check of the original question are safer.

Comment: Where have you seen their recommendation - do you have a link? (Not that I doubt you, I just haven't seen them say that!)

Comment: The section named [Using Weakly Linked Classes in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html). Your method is prone to developer error and also doesn't allow for future release changes.

Comment: That is kind of what I read too and why I didn't jump at that option.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely not future proof - it's just example code :) The link you show is absolutely right to determine if a class is available but that's not what the OP wants - he doesn't want to use the`UICollectionView` class, he's using it's presence to indicate an iOS version; a method which is just as prone to developer error imho. (@AdamLongfellow - please correct me if my assumption is wrong!)

Comment: That's correct. It's a hack to just show different buttons to the versions (Maps is forcing a change so I can offer a new button, old users don't have it, iOS6 people do). I just want the 5.1 code to acknowledge something it doesn't know anything about yet instead of going backward which is more common.